# Search algorithm for multidimensional space with custom topology

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, search-trees, modelling

First, let's start with the description of the problem in **dimension 1**:

Let $T_0$ be a space with $n$ nodes organized in a tree structure, with $m$ of those nodes defined as target nodes. In this space, we define a function $f(node)$ that associates each node to the first target node in the path to the root.

So, as an example, given the space defined by the image below

[image]

we have the following: $f(F) = C$, $f(E) = E$ and $f(D) = A$ .
In this space, an "efficient" algorithm

---

We can now define a multidimensional space defined as the cartesian product of spaces similar to $T_0$, each with a different set of nodes and a different tree structure, and with two key differences:

1. The target nodes are defined on the product space
2. The order in the cartesian product space defines the priority when defining the distance between two solutions. So, any distance between any two nodes in a tree is shorter than the distance between any other two nodes in a space on its left on the cartesian product.

So, for example, a 2 dimensional space $T0 * T1$ defined as in the image below:

[image]

Given the set of target nodes ${(A, u), (B, x), (F, w), (C, x)}$, then

- $f((B, x)) = (B, x)$
- $f((B, z)) = (B, x)$
- $f((F, x)) = (F, w)$ chosen over $(C, x)$ because distances in $T1$ is shorter than any other distance in $T0$ by definition

---

So, the question is, is there any algorithm that can be applied to this space in order to efficiently compute $f$?

So far I have considered two options:

1. Put all the elements of the space in a map with value the target node. While this approach has a great time complexity, the space complexity is way too high when the cartesian product is made of several $T_i$
2. Order the target nodes based on the distance defined above (single space topology + order in the cartesian product), but this approach has linear time complexity in the number of target node, which is less than ideal.

Neither of them is fully satisfactory, which is why I am reaching out for ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by '"closest" node between its predecessor'?  A node has only one predecessor, so I'm not sure what candidates you are choosing among.  How are you measuring/defining the distance between two nodes?

Comment: I think he meant that it is the first node in the path to the root, that is a "target node" (marked in red)

Comment: @D.W. sorry for the confusion, nir shahar definition is correct: I meant the first target node in the path to the root. I will update the description to reflect that.